# Core data : Insert two entites, save one without the other

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to create two entities at the same time and I want to save just one of them. Anyone know how to do this? I have tried multiple managed object context but it's not working.

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an Entity1 which have a list of Entity2. Entity2 can be linked to several Entity1.
In my view to create/Update the Entity1 I can add Entity2s. To do this I push an another view controller to add/update Entity2.
When I have terminate to fill the Entity2's datas, I save the datas and return to the view controller to add/Update Entity 1 with the new Entity2 object add in the list. But because of the save the incomplete datas of the entity 1 are save too... I don't know if it's clear.

Comment: When do you trigger the save? And you consider an E1 with no E2 linked to it is an incomplete object?

Comment: I trigger two save, One in the E2 view controller and another in the E1 view controller when all the datas are filled.
And No E1 can not have E2, E1 have others properties.

Comment: I can explain the problem with another example more simple.
If you have two entities in a TabBarApplicattion. Each tabs can manage (create) one of the entities.
I start to fill partially an entity in the first tab, I change of tabs and i fill the data of the other entity in the second tab and press save. I want that only the change of the seconds tab are saved.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement, don't create the entity instance until the save button is pressed. Store all of the entered data into something else, like a dictionary, until the save button is pressed.

Generally I would recommend against this and I would save the current data whenever the user has entered it - i.e. what you have now.

Comment: Yes I Have already do this and It's work. You can even Create entity without link to the context to do this ( see example ) but I want to use good pattern like this : http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ ( the last in the article ).

Example :
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Entity entity = [[Exercice alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

//Use the entity

//Save it
[moc insertObject:newExercice];
[moc save:....

Comment: I have made mistake in my example :
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Entity *entity = [[Exercice alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

//Use the entity

//Save it
[context insertObject:entity];
[context save:....

Comment: I would say the good pattern is to create and save the objects as the user enters the data, just in case they need to close the app, battery runs out, app crashes. Try to loose as little of the entered info as possible...